# Django channels unable to connect(find) websocket after dockerize the project

Tags: django, docker, nginx, websocket, django-channels

**Before trying to containerize the application with docker, it worked well with:**
`python manage.py runserver`
with the following settings.py setction for the redis layer:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("0.0.0.0", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

and by calling a docker container for the redis layer:
`docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5`
**But after trying to containerize the entire application it was unable to find the websocket:**
Error message in firefox console :
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEpib.png)
docker-compose file:

```
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always

  wsgiserver:
    container_name: wsgiserver
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/source/
    expose:
      - "8000"
    networks:
      - main
    environment:
      - EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_email@example.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=your_email_password
      - CHANNEL_LAYERS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    restart: always

  asgiserver:
    container_name: asgiserver
    build: .
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 9000 ChatApp.asgi:application
    volumes:
      - .:/source/
    expose:
      - "9000"
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - wsgiserver
    restart: always

  celery_worker:
    container_name: celery_worker
    command: "celery -A ChatApp worker -l INFO"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - wsgiserver
      - asgiserver
    build: .
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_TIMEZONE=Asia/Tehran
    networks:
      - main
    restart: always

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    depends_on:
      - wsgiserver
      - asgiserver
    image: nginx:1.25
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - ./media:/app/media

networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx conf :

```
http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log     /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;

        location /static/ {
            alias /app/staticfiles/;
        }
        location /media/ {
            alias /app/media/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header    Host app;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_pass http://wsgiserver:8000;
        }

        # ASGI
        # map websocket connection to daphne
        location /ws {
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_ws;
        }

        location @proxy_to_ws {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass  http://asgiserver:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from chat_app.routing import websocket_urlpatterns


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ChatApp.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
    ),
})
```

settings.py section for redis layer :

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS_HOST = os.environ.get('CHANNEL_LAYERS_HOST', 'localhost')
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(CHANNEL_LAYERS_HOST, 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

JavaScript codes for websocket :

```
let ws_scheme = window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws';
const chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
    ws_scheme
    +'://'
    + window.location.host
    + '/ws/chat/'
    + roomName
    + '/'
);
const chatSocket2 = new WebSocket(
    'ws://'
     + window.location.host
     + '/ws/chat/'
     + 'listener'
     + '/'
);
```

I have tried many ways and have not been able to solve the problem. I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem. I have also uploaded this project to my GitHub account, which is not yet Dockerized. If you are interested, you can add Docker to it and send a Pull request and be considered as a contributor. Thank you.
[Github](https://github.com/Aron-S-G-H/django-chat-application)